# flutter- how should I handle app version by using package_info?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to know how to handle app version.
I guess I should use this [package_info](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/package_info).

There is a method to get version like so.

```
String version = packageInfo.version;
```

I guess after get the version, I should compare this to new version which fetched from server or something.
Am I right?
Plus, is this returning Android versionCode or versionName?
What about iOS?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/package_info/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/packageinfo/PackageInfoPlugin.java - here is code for android - it returns version name. In this repository you can also look sources for iOS

Comment: package_info is to find out what the version is already set to natively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change your app version for Android you will have to go to the build.gradle and set the version code and name inside the defaultConfig element

```
defaultConfig { 
  minSdkVersion 9 
  targetSdkVersion 19 
  versionCode 1
  versionName "1.0" 
}
```

As for iOS, you can read about that [here](https://flutter.io/docs/deployment/ios)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your version from file **pubspec.yaml**.

```
version: 1.0.0+1
```

**Note that '1.0.0' is your version name, and after '+' is your build number.**

For more information about versioning, you can go to this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html